# Python poetry install failure - invalid hashes

Tags: python, numpy, python-poetry

I'm unsure exactly what information / context to provide with this post in order for it to be
properly answered - so if I can add more information please let me know.

Whilst trying to install a package I've had an error message as follows:

```
  Invalid hashes (sha256:01d6b62184e55367ce7d770bd87d97a6cfaf783ff7ba8328e7473a339fe19807) for numpy (1.22.2)
```

I don't know how to go about troubleshooting this problem.

## `poetry --version`

```
(install-check-clU745_7-py3.8) ➜  install_check poetry --version
Poetry version 1.1.12
```

## `poetry env info`

Output of `poetry env info`:

```
(install-check-clU745_7-py3.8) ➜  install_check poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.8.12
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/user_name/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/install-check-clU745_7-py3.8
Valid:          True

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12
```

## pyproject.toml

`pyproject.toml` config:

```
(install-check-clU745_7-py3.8) ➜  install_check cat pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "install_check"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["user_name <user_name@email_add.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

## Steps to reproduce

Here is an attempt to clearly outline a reproduction of this problem:

```sh
python --version
    Python 3.8.12

which python
    /Users/user_name/.pyenv/shims/python

poetry new install_check
    Created package install_check in install_check

cd install_check

cat pyproject.toml| grep python
    python = "^3.7"

# update pyproject.toml to 3.8 instead of 3.7.

cat pyproject.toml | grep python
    python = "^3.8"

python --version
    Python 3.8.12

poetry env use python3.8

which python3.8
    /Users/user_name/.pyenv/shims/python3.8

poetry env use python3.8

poetry install
    Updating dependencies
    Resolving dependencies... (5.0s)

    Writing lock file

    Package operations: 8 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

    • Installing pyparsing (3.0.7)
    • Installing attrs (21.4.0)
    • Installing more-itertools (8.12.0)
    • Installing packaging (21.3)
    • Installing pluggy (0.13.1)
    • Installing py (1.11.0)
    • Installing wcwidth (0.2.5)
    • Installing pytest (5.4.3)

    Installing the current project: install_check (0.1.0)
```

Following this, after leaving and revisiting the directory to activate the env, I have:

```
(install-check-clU745_7-py3.8) ➜  install_check which python
/Users/user_name/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/install-check-clU745_7-py3.8/bin/python
(install-check-clU745_7-py3.8) ➜  install_check python --version
Python 3.8.12
```

Trying to add pandas then gives the following error:

```
(install-check-clU745_7-py3.8) ➜  install_check poetry add pandas
Using version ^1.4.0 for pandas

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (2.3s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing six (1.16.0)
  • Installing numpy (1.22.2): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Invalid hashes (sha256:01d6b62184e55367ce7d770bd87d97a6cfaf783ff7ba8328e7473a339fe19807) for numpy (1.22.2) using archive numpy-1.22.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl. Expected one of sha256:03ae5850619abb34a879d5f2d4bb4dcd025d6d8fb72f5e461dae84edccfe129f, sha256:076aee5a3763d41da6bef9565fdf3cb987606f567cd8b104aded2b38b7b47abf, sha256:0b536b6840e84c1c6a410f3a5aa727821e6108f3454d81a5cd5900999ef04f89, sha256:15efb7b93806d438e3bc590ca8ef2f953b0ce4f86f337ef4559d31ec6cf9d7dd, sha256:168259b1b184aa83a514f307352c25c56af111c269ffc109d9704e81f72e764b, sha256:2638389562bda1635b564490d76713695ff497242a83d9b684d27bb4a6cc9d7a, sha256:3556c5550de40027d3121ebbb170f61bbe19eb639c7ad0c7b482cd9b560cd23b, sha256:4a176959b6e7e00b5a0d6f549a479f869829bfd8150282c590deee6d099bbb6e, sha256:515a8b6edbb904594685da6e176ac9fbea8f73a5ebae947281de6613e27f1956, sha256:55535c7c2f61e2b2fc817c5cbe1af7cb907c7f011e46ae0a52caa4be1f19afe2, sha256:59153979d60f5bfe9e4c00e401e24dfe0469ef8da6d68247439d3278f30a180f, sha256:60cb8e5933193a3cc2912ee29ca331e9c15b2da034f76159b7abc520b3d1233a, sha256:6767ad399e9327bfdbaa40871be4254d1995f4a3ca3806127f10cec778bd9896, sha256:76a4f9bce0278becc2da7da3b8ef854bed41a991f4226911a24a9711baad672c, sha256:8cf33634b60c9cef346663a222d9841d3bbbc0a2f00221d6bcfd0d993d5543f6, sha256:94dd11d9f13ea1be17bac39c1942f527cbf7065f94953cf62dfe805653da2f8f, sha256:aafa46b5a39a27aca566198d3312fb3bde95ce9677085efd02c86f7ef6be4ec7, sha256:badca914580eb46385e7f7e4e426fea6de0a37b9e06bec252e481ae7ec287082, sha256:d76a26c5118c4d96e264acc9e3242d72e1a2b92e739807b3b69d8d47684b6677.

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/installation/executor.py:632 in _download_link
      628│                     "Invalid hashes ({}) for {} using archive {}. Expected one of {}.".format(
      629│                         ", ".join(sorted(archive_hashes)),
      630│                         package,
      631│                         archive_path.name,
    → 632│                         ", ".join(sorted(hashes)),
      633│                     )
      634│                 )
      635│
      636│         return archive

  • Installing python-dateutil (2.8.2)
  • Installing pytz (2021.3)

Failed to add packages, reverting the pyproject.toml file to its original content.
```

## Attempt to solve

### remove existing poetry installation

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
```

### install specific poetry version

Trying to following [this issue comment](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4523#issuecomment-1022056874) I installed with:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --version 1.1.8
```

### Try creating another env like before (Still fails)

I'm still getting failures.

```
python --version
    Python 3.8.12

poetry --version
    Poetry version 1.1.8

poetry new install_check_2
    Created package install_check_2 in install_check_2

cd install_check_2
```

Then within the newly created project:

```
poetry env use python3.8
    Creating virtualenv install-check-2-1m3rSWN1-py3.8 in /Users/user_name/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs
    Using virtualenv: /Users/user_name/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/install-check-2-1m3rSWN1-py3.8

poetry install
    Updating dependencies
    Resolving dependencies... (4.9s)

    Writing lock file

    Package operations: 8 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

    • Installing pyparsing (3.0.7): Failed

    AttributeError

    'Link' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'

    at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/core/packages/file_dependency.py:33 in __init__
        29│         self._path = path
        30│         self._base = base or Path.cwd()
        31│         self._full_path = path
        32│
        →  33│         if not self._path.is_absolute():
        34│             try:
        35│                 self._full_path = self._base.joinpath(self._path).resolve()
        36│             except FileNotFoundError:
        37│                 raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
```

Comment: That seem to be an open issue with poetry https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4523

Comment: @SimonHawe Thanks. I can't believe that people aren't currently able to install something like pandas with poetry though,? Added some further attempts to the post.

Comment: You can try to manually put some of those hash values into your lock file or you can for the time being pin the numpy version to 1.21.4, or what alsp helped me is to completely delete the lock file. However, after that I could only get it work on my mac but not in our docker containers ...

Comment: "manually put some of those hash values into your lock file", I think i'd stop using a tool long before I started manually entering hash values.

Comment: Removing `~/.cache/pypoetry/cache/` and `~/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/` might help. If you're on mac: `~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/cache/` and `~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts`. You probably canceled poetry update or installation and caches became corrupted

Comment: ```Removing ~/.cache/pypoetry/cache/ and ~/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ might help. If you're on mac: ~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/cache/ and ~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts. You probably canceled poetry update or installation and caches became corrupted```WORKED FOR ME

Comment: Yihou Zhou's comment resolved the issue for me. @yih please repost as a proposed answer, because it is at the least a usable workaround.

Answer (score 55):

There are [several](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5142) [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4883) [reports](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4523) about invalid hashes. One common cause is running multiple Poetry instances simultaneously; another is aborted downloads (e.g. ^C). Poetry should be fixed to make corruption less likely to happen in such cases, and perhaps to try downloading corrupted files again automatically.

Until then, the workaround is to remove the offending file from the cache and let Poetry download a fresh copy.

You can find the full path to the offending file like this:

```
$ find ~/.cache/pypoetry -name numpy-1.22.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl
```

Or, for the lazy, just blow away the entire cache:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/pypoetry
```

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas,  running multiple Poetry instances simultaneously was the culprit in my case!

Comment: Spent over an hour trying to fix this. Blowing away the entire cache did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Allowing ^C during a long operation to lead to a broken environment is pretty bad.  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: If your `~/.cache/pypoetry` contains symlinks, be sure to follow them via `find -L`.

Answer (score 44):

I `ctrl-C`'d during a `poetry install`, which caused one of the cached wheels to partially download and have a hash that didn't match what was on PyPI.

On macOS with Poetry 1.1.13, the only method that worked for me was [Yihua Zhou's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71001968/python-poetry-install-failure-invalid-hashes#comment126843341_71001968):

```bash
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/cache
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts
```

Comment: In my case removing artifacts helped, but removing cache did not help

Comment: Same here, removing artifacts is the ticket. Thanks @phoenix!

Comment: what a simple solution to an enigmatic error

Comment: Perhaps the error message should give a path to the cache, I cleared many caches before that one did the trick.

Comment: goddamn this was annoying me. Everything I do to try and make my python install completely independent of macOS idiosyncrasies and poetry still uses the MacOS library...

Comment: I have python 3.6 environments so I wanted to stay with poetry 1.1.x. I was using poetry v1.1.13 and encountered this issue. Upgraded to v1.1.15, ran `poetry lock` and noticed additional file hashes were added to the lock. Upgrading fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had to remove both. Wasted half a day on this installing and uninstalling this and that until I came up on this answer.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe this is a solution:

```
poetry cache clear . --all
rm poetry.lock
poetry install
```

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4523#issuecomment-923155835

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this in a Docker image, in addition to the answers above I also had to do:

```
docker builder prune
```

This could be necessary if taking using some of the more recent docker build caching features in the Dockerfile such as:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR/cache \
    --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR/artifacts \
    poetry install
```

This is because the poetry cache is on the host file system and needs to be cleared for same reason as the answers above.

Answer (score 2):

Pruning cache didn't work for me, and I could not resovle this via changing poetry version. However, I found another workaround - installing packages (pinned to the desired versions) manually:

```
poetry run pip install json-log-formatter==0.4.0
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Before searching for a solution it might be worth to simply **try again**.

Sometimes this error appears randomly (I also had more persistant issues like the one people reportd in this thread before).

In that particular case, I had a skaffold build (helm) that got this error, I just re-ran the exact same build and didn't get the error the second time.

Specifically, I had the following error:

```bash
Hash for botocore (1.29.76) from archive botocore-1.29.76-py3-none-any.whl not found in known hashes (was: sha256:2cd6fa99f8ec53560793ff884ec02713e9627293859c4841cf18b93153c9ebb6)
#12 3.763
#12 3.763   at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/executor.py:761 in _validate_archive_hash
#12 3.777       757│         archive_hash: str = "sha256:" + get_file_hash(archive)
#12 3.777       758│         known_hashes = {f["hash"] for f in package.files if f["file"] == archive.name}
#12 3.777       759│
#12 3.777       760│         if archive_hash not in known_hashes:
#12 3.777     → 761│             raise RuntimeError(
#12 3.777       762│                 f"Hash for {package} from archive {archive.name} not found in"
#12 3.777       763│                 f" known hashes (was: {archive_hash})"
#12 3.777       764│             )
#12 3.777       765│
#12 3.777
```

Comment: Usually it works on the second try. Most I've seen is four.